Crash Report Error in xcode for SwiftUI: ForEachChild.updateValue
I'm seeing this crash report error:
(myAppName) closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in myView.body.getter
SwiftUI     closure #1 in ForEachChild.updateValue()
SwiftUI     partial apply for closure #1 in ForEachChild.updateValue()
SwiftUI     runApp<A>(_:)
SwiftUI     static App.main()

I've narrowed down the closure to be this ForEach. But I don't see anything that could cause a crash here. What does ForEachChild.updateValue() actually mean?
let indices: (Int, Int) = getIndices()
if indices.0 <= indices.1 {
    ForEach(indices.0...indices.1, id:\.self) { idx in
        let element: Data = model.getData(idx)
        showDataView(id: element.id, name: element.name, index: idx, geometry: geom.size)
            .frame(widthL geom.size.width, height:geom.size.height)
            .offset(x: CGFloat(idx) * geom.size.width)
    }
}


Indicies are unsafe

restructure your code, as mentioned using indicies is not a good idea. What is index in your mode.getData(index), should it be idx?

@workingdogsupportUkraine I've modified the code.

@loremipsum May i know how is indicies unsafe?

You haven’t included the actual error message and only a code snippet taken out of context so we can’t reproduce the crash either or fully understand what the code does.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
Some (minimal) code we can compile and run, together with the full error message.
Note, it seems that you have your own Data type,
in let element: Data = model.getData(idx). However
Swift already has a Data type, so you will eventually comfuse
yourself and the compiler, change its name.

Watch Demistify SwiftUI there is a section on the topic.

id:\.self is a pretty obvious mistake, it needs to be the key path to the data’s identifier.

Hi, may i know why is it a mistake? I've followed this tutorial to loop through an int range. the value itself is the identifier right? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach

best stick to apple's tutorials
